# C# Unity why is module loading too late?

Tags: c#, wpf, module, unity-container

I have a module "Toolbar", "Toolbar" contains a UserControl and a ViewModel. The viewmodel is supposed to get a service called "IShapeService" injected into its constructor, however there's an issue.

I get the following error message when running my application:

```
The current type, Core.Services.IShapeService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. 
Are you missing a type mapping?
```

The interface is mapped to the type in the ServicesModule which you can see below.

```
public class ServicesModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public ServicesModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        container.RegisterType<IShapeService, ShapeService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell by debugging, the issue is that the ServicesModule is not loaded early enough. I quickly tried using a PriorityAttribute (you can find it via google) on the module, but had no luck this time.

The weird thing is that it is working in another project with the same setup (as far I can see it is the same setup). The other project actually also uses the PriorityAttribute, but it is to determine tab order.

This is an image of the solution structure:

[image]

All projects reference the Core, but that is also it.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `ServicesModule.Initialize()` run **before** you or unity is trying to create the Toolbar?

Comment: Unity tries to initialize ToolbarModule before it tries to initialize ServicesModule.

Comment: I would do unity configuration first thing in the application. Unity doesn't try to initialize something out of good will :) Something is requesting the  ToolbarModule, and nothing has called the initialize... I know its the same you are saying. but who should call initialize? cant you call it before?